# How to configure Laravel Homestead to start beanstalkd queue worker after provisioning/booting?

Tags: php, laravel, vagrant, homestead, beanstalkd

I am down with setting up Homestead and all. Now I am trying to start the queue worker daemon after each provisioning / vagrant up. How can I accomplish that?

I have tried to add the following to my `.homestead/after.sh` file:

```
nohup php project_name/artisan queue:work local --daemon --sleep=3 --tries=3 >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

But no luck. My console starts hanging and the vagrant/ruby processes must be killed.

Not sure if this is the right place to put it at all? Or does it need to be somewhere else, so it will be started on each `vagrant up`?

Comment: can you create a script and push into init.d as part of the initial provisioning so it will run on boot